# Bootstrap list - shrink and eliminate border

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface

I have created a Bootstrap list using `list-group` and `list-group-item`.

Unfortunately every list item occupies a lot of space:

[image]

I would like to shrink the size of every `list-group-item` element.

I would also like to eliminate the border.

I understand that this can be done with CSS.
However, I'm not familiar with it.
How can I do these changes?

Answer (score 1):

The list group is being fitted to the size of the column in bootstrap so reduce that to reduce the size.

As for the border, the list inherits the class `.list-group-item`. You could write you own css to override the bootstrap theme with something like:

```
.list-group-item {
     border-style: none;
}
```

Comment: I have added this code to my CSS file, which I've referenced from my HTML file. Unfortunatelly, nothing changed.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a custom CSS to your project / site and override the original bootstrap definitions like this:

```
.list-group-item {
    border:0 !important;
    padding-top:2px !important;
    padding-bottom:2px !important;
}
```

You have to override the padding of the `.list-group-items`. An example you can see on this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sebastianbrosch/vqLzncbk/

The border can be removed from bootstrap itself by customizing the download on the following site: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#list-group

Comment: I have added your code in my CSS file and I referenced this file in my `index.html` like this: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="list.css">`
However, padding and borders look the same.

Comment: can you post a link or fiddle with the whole code. the custom css have to add after the bootstrap.css.